# How to solve this trigonometric integral analytically

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to solve the following integral analytically :

```
Integrate[
 1/(a + b Cos[x - y])*1/(c + d Cos[x - z])*1/(
  e + f Cos[z - y]), {x, 0, 2 Pi} , {y, 0, 2 Pi}, {z, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

and I want to Solve for arbitrary **Real** values of a,b,c,d,e,f.
the integrate works when I give some values to a,b,c,d,e,f but when I don't ,the process is interminable and doesn't seem to give an answer ! 
I should also note that the arbitrary values are chosen in a way that the integral is not singular , for example a>b.
I appreciate your time .

**EDIT**

I just found out numerically that the integral can be substituted with this one :

```
2*Pi*Integrate[
 1/(a + b Cos[x])*1/(c + d Cos[y])*1/(
  e + f Cos[x-y]), {x, 0, 2 Pi} , {y, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

So now problem reduces to a two dimensional angle integration rather than three.

Comment: While it won't resolve your issue, you should start by replacing all instances of `pi` with `Pi`

Comment: Any reason to expect this integral can be expressed in terms of elementary functions? Especially for arbitrary complex $a,b,c,d,e,f$?

Comment: Thanks bob @BobHanlon

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that a,b,c,d,e values are Real . I know that when I sum the angles rather than subtracting them , the result can be turned into three separate integrals over the angles , and then can be solved easily. but I'm not sure about this one .@AccidentalFourierTransform

Comment: One may assume $a=1,c=1,e=1,|b|<1,|d|<1,|f|<1$ without loss of generality.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks . that would probably make it easier for mathematica to handle. @user64494

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No chance at  present.The command

```
Integrate[ 1/(1 + b Cos[x - y])*1/(1 + d Cos[x - z])*1/(1 + f Cos[z - y]), {x,0, 2 Pi}, 

{y, 0, 2 Pi},{z, 0, 2*Pi},Assumptions -> b < 1 &&b >-1 && d < 1 &&d>-1 &&f < 1 && f > -1]
```

fails. Even

```
Integrate[1/(1 + b Cos[x - y])*1/(1 + d Cos[x - z])*1/(1 - 1/4* Cos[z - y]), {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
{y, 0, 2 Pi}, {z, 0, 2*Pi},Assumptions -> b < 1 && b > -1 && d < 1 && d > -1]
```

> (1/(15 Sqrt[1-d^2]))16 [Pi] Integrate[(60 d^2+Sqrt[15] Sqrt[1-d^2]+d (15+4 Sqrt[15] Sqrt[1-d^2]) Cos[x-y])/((1+b Cos[x-y]) (2+31 d^2+d^2 Cos[2 x-2 y]+16 d Cos[x-y])),{x,0,2 [Pi]},{y,0,2 [Pi]},Assumptions->b<1&&b>-1&&d<1&&d>-1]

The following works.

```
Integrate[ 1/(1 + 1/2* Cos[x - y])*1/(1 + 1/3*Cos[x - z])*1/(1 - 
 1/4* Cos[z - y]), {x, 0, 2* Pi}, {y, 0, 2 *Pi}, {z, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

> $$\frac{8}{5} \left(2 \sqrt{5}+\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{30}-6\right) \pi ^3 $$

The result is confirmed numerically.

Addition. The modified question has an affirmative answer:

```
Integrate[ 1/(1 + b Cos[x])*1/(1 + d Cos[y])*1/(1 + f Cos[x - y]), {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
{y, 0, 2 Pi}, Assumptions -> b > -1 && b < 1 && d > -1 && d < 1 && f > -1 && f < 1]
```

> ConditionalExpression[(4 (Sqrt[1-b^2] d^2 f^2 (-Sqrt[1-d^2]+Sqrt[1-d^2] f^2-Sqrt[1-f^2]+d^2 Sqrt[1-f^2])-b^2 (Sqrt[1-d^2] f^2+d^2 Sqrt[1-f^2]) Sqrt[-(-1+d^2) (-1+f^2) (d^2+f^2-2 (1+Sqrt[(-1+d^2) (-1+f^2)]))]+b d f (-f^2 Sqrt[(-1+b^2) (-1+f^2)]+Sqrt[1-b^2] d^2 (-Sqrt[1-d^2]+f^2 (Sqrt[1-d^2]+Sqrt[1-f^2]))-(Sqrt[1-d^2]+Sqrt[1-f^2]) Sqrt[-(-1+d^2) (-1+f^2) (d^2+f^2-2 (1+Sqrt[(-1+d^2) (-1+f^2)]))])) [Pi]^2)/(Sqrt[(-1+d^2) (-1+f^2)] (-2 b d f-d^2 f^2+b^2 (-f^2+d^2 (-1+f^2))) Sqrt[(-1+b^2) (-1+d^2) (-1+f^2) (d^2+f^2-2 (1+Sqrt[(-1+d^2) (-1+f^2)]))]),b!=0]

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer , unfortunately the coefficients are functions of some other variable . maybe I should consider the possible ways of solving it by hand.

Comment: Hi , Please take a look at my edit . tnx . @user64494